# Right way to parse chain of various binary functions with `Parsec`?

Tags: parsing, haskell, operator-precedence, parsec, associativity

It is true that `Parsec` has `chainl` and `chainr` to parse chains of either left-associative or right-associative **operations** (i.e. `a -> a -> a`). So I could quite easily parse something like `x + y + z` in a `((a + y) + z)` or `(a + (y + z))` manner.

However,

1. there is no standard way to parse `a -> b -> c` **functions** and specific case when `a = b`: `a -> a -> c`, for example `a = b = c` thought as a comparison function (`a -> a -> Bool`);
2. there is no standard way to implement "importance" of an operation: for example `a + b = b + a` should be parsed as `((a + b) = (b + a))` and not `(((a + b) = b) + a))`.

I am kind of new to parsing problems, so it would be great to get answers for both questions.

Comment: For number 1, you have to decide what result you want. Should `a = b = c` produce `(= (= a b) c)`, `(= a (= b c))`, or `(= a b c)`? For number 2, you just need separate grammar rules for `+` and `=`, so that `(= (+ a b) (b + a))` is the only legal parsing of `a + b = b + a`.

Comment: If you just want to get it done without understanding how it works, use [`Parsec.Expr.buildExpressionParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html).

Comment: And if do you want to understand how it works, you could work through the definition of `buildExpressionParser` for your working parser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, here's a long answer that might help. First, these are the imports I'm using, if you want to follow along:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
import Control.Applicative (some)
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.String
```

### Why `a -> a -> a` isn't so bad...

The operator type signature `a -> a -> a` is less restrictive and makes more sense than you might at first think.  One key point is that *usually* when we're parsing expressions, we don't write a parser to evaluate them directly but rather parse them into some intermediate abstract syntax tree (AST) that is later evaluated.  For example, consider a simple untyped AST with addition, subtraction, equality, and boolean connectives:

```
data Expr
  = IntE Int        -- integer literals
  | FalseE | TrueE  -- boolean literals (F, T)
  | AddE Expr Expr  -- x + y
  | SubE Expr Expr  -- x - y
  | EqE  Expr Expr  -- x = y
  | OrE  Expr Expr  -- x | y
  | AndE Expr Expr  -- x & y
  deriving (Show)
```

If we want to write a parser to treat all these operators as left associative at the same precedence level, we can write a `chainl`-based parser like so.  (For simplicity, this parser doesn't permit whitespace.)

```
expr :: Parser Expr
expr = chainl1 term op
  where op = AddE <$ char '+'
         <|> SubE <$ char '-'
         <|> EqE  <$ char '='
         <|> OrE  <$ char '|'
         <|> AndE <$ char '&'
term :: Parser Expr
term = IntE . read <$> some digit
   <|> FalseE <$ char 'F' <|> TrueE <$ char 'T'
   <|> parens expr
parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens = between (char '(') (char ')')
```

and we get:

```
> parseTest expr "1+2+3"
AddE (AddE (IntE 1) (IntE 2)) (IntE 3)
> parseTest expr "1=2=F"
EqE (EqE (IntE 1) (IntE 2)) FalseE
>
```

We'd then leave it up to the interpreter to deal with the types (i.e., to type check the program):

```
data Value = BoolV Bool | IntV Int deriving (Eq, Show)
eval :: Expr -> Value
eval (IntE x) = IntV x
eval FalseE = BoolV False
eval TrueE = BoolV True
eval (AddE e1 e2)
  = let IntV v1 = eval e1  -- pattern match ensures right type
        IntV v2 = eval e2
    in  IntV (v1 + v2)
eval (SubE e1 e2)
  = let IntV v1 = eval e1
        IntV v2 = eval e2
    in  IntV (v1 - v2)
eval (EqE e1 e2) = BoolV (eval e1 == eval e2)  -- equal if same type and value
eval (OrE e1 e2)
  = let BoolV v1 = eval e1
        BoolV v2 = eval e2
    in  BoolV (v1 || v2)
eval (AndE e1 e2)
  = let BoolV v1 = eval e1
        BoolV v2 = eval e2
    in  BoolV (v1 && v2)

evalExpr :: String -> Value
evalExpr str = let Right e = parse expr "<evalExpr>" str in eval e
```

giving:

```
> evalExpr "1+2+3"
IntV 6
> evalExpr "1=2=F"
BoolV True
>
```

Note that even though the type of the "`=`" operator is something like `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` (or actually `a -> b -> Bool`, as we allow comparison of unequal types), it's represented in the AST as the constructor `EqE` of type `Expr -> Expr -> Expr`, so the `a -> a -> a` type makes sense.

Even if we were to combine the parser and evaluator above into a single function, we'd probably find it easiest to use a dynamic `Value` type, so all operators would be of type `Value -> Value -> Value` which fits into the `a -> a -> a` pattern:

```
expr' :: Parser Value
expr' = chainl1 term' op
  where op = add <$ char '+'
         <|> sub <$ char '-'
         <|> eq  <$ char '='
         <|> or  <$ char '|'
         <|> and <$ char '&'
        add (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x + y
        sub (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x - y
        eq  v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        or  (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x || y
        and (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x && y
term' :: Parser Value
term' = IntV . read <$> some digit
   <|> BoolV False <$ char 'F' <|> BoolV True <$ char 'T'
   <|> parens expr'
```

This works too, with the parser directly evaluating the expression

```
> parseTest expr' "1+2+3"
IntV 6
> parseTest expr' "1=2=F"
BoolV True
>
```

You may find this use of dynamic typing during parsing and evaluation a little unsatifactory, but see below.

### Operator Precedence

The standard way of adding operator precedence is to define multiple expression "levels" that work with a subset of the operators.  If we want a precedence ordering from highest to lowest of addition/subtraction, then equality, then boolean "and", then boolean "or", we could replace `expr'` with the following.  Note that each `chainl1` call uses as "terms" the next (higher-precedence) expression level:

```
expr0 :: Parser Value
expr0 = chainl1 expr1 op
  where op = or  <$ char '|'
        or  (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x || y
expr1 :: Parser Value
expr1 = chainl1 expr2 op
  where op = and <$ char '&'
        and (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x && y
expr2 :: Parser Value
expr2 = chainl1 expr3 op
  where op = eq  <$ char '='
        eq  v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
expr3 :: Parser Value
expr3 = chainl1 term'' op
  where op = add <$ char '+'  -- two operators at same precedence
         <|> sub <$ char '-'
        add (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x + y
        sub (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x - y
term'' :: Parser Value
term'' = IntV . read <$> some digit
     <|> BoolV False <$ char 'F' <|> BoolV True <$ char 'T'
     <|> parens expr0
```

After which:

```
> parseTest expr0 "(1+5-6=2-3+1&2+2=4)=(T|F)"
BoolV True
>
```

As this can be tedious, Parsec provides a `Text.Parsec.Expr` that makes this easier.  The following replaces `expr0` through `expr3` above:

```
expr0' :: Parser Value
expr0' = buildExpressionParser table term''
  where table = [ [binary '+' add, binary '-' sub]
                , [binary '=' eq]
                , [binary '&' and]
                , [binary '|' or]
                ]
        binary c op = Infix (op <$ char c) AssocLeft
        add (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x + y
        sub (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x - y
        eq  v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        and (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x && y
        or  (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x || y
```

### Typed Parsing

You may find it strange above that we use an untyped AST (i.e., everything's an `Expr`) and dynamically typed `Value` instead of using Haskell's type system in the parsing.  It is possible to design a parser where the operators actually have expected Haskell types.  In the language above, equality causes a bit of an issue, but if we permit integer equality only, it's possible to write a typed parser/evaluator as follows.  Here `bexpr` and `iexpr` are for boolean-valued and integer-values expressions respectively.

```
bexpr0 :: Parser Bool
bexpr0 = chainl1 bexpr1 op
  where op = (||) <$ char '|'
bexpr1 :: Parser Bool
bexpr1 = chainl1 bexpr2 op
  where op = (&&) <$ char '&'
bexpr2 :: Parser Bool
bexpr2 = False <$ char 'F' <|> True <$ char 'T'
     <|> try eqexpr
     <|> parens bexpr0
     where eqexpr = (==) <$> iexpr3 <* char '=' <*> iexpr3  -- this can't chain now
iexpr3 :: Parser Int
iexpr3 = chainl1 iterm op
  where op = (+) <$ char '+'
         <|> (-) <$ char '-'
iterm :: Parser Int
iterm = read <$> some digit
     <|> parens iexpr3
```

Note that we're still able to use `chainl1`, but there's a boundary between the integer and boolean types enforced by precedence, so we only ever chain `Int -> Int -> Int` or `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` operators, and we don't let the `Int -> Int -> Bool` integer equality operator chain.

This also means we need to use a different parser to parse a boolean versus an integer expression:

```
> parseTest bexpr0 "1+2=3"
True
> parseTest iexpr3 "1+2-3"  -- iexpr3 is top-most integer expression parser
0
>
```

Note here that if you wanted integer equality to chain as a set of equalities so that `1+1=2=3-1` would check that all three terms are equal, you could do this with `chainl1` using some trickery with lists and singleton values, but it's easier to use `sepBy1` and replace `eqexpr` above with the definition:

```
eqexpr' = do
  x:xs <- sepBy1 iexpr3 (char '=')
  return $ all (==x) xs
```

giving:

```
> parseTest bexpr0 "1+1=2=3-1"
True
```

### The whole program

To summarize, here's all the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Control.Applicative (some)
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.String

-- * Untyped parser to AST

data Expr
  = IntE Int        -- integer literals
  | FalseE | TrueE  -- boolean literals (F, T)
  | AddE Expr Expr  -- x + y
  | SubE Expr Expr  -- x - y
  | EqE  Expr Expr  -- x = y
  | OrE  Expr Expr  -- x | y
  | AndE Expr Expr  -- x & y
  deriving (Show)

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = chainl1 term op
  where op = AddE <$ char '+'
         <|> SubE <$ char '-'
         <|> EqE  <$ char '='
         <|> OrE  <$ char '|'
         <|> AndE <$ char '&'

term :: Parser Expr
term = IntE . read <$> some digit
   <|> FalseE <$ char 'F' <|> TrueE <$ char 'T'
   <|> parens expr

parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens = between (char '(') (char ')')

-- * Interpreter

data Value = BoolV Bool | IntV Int deriving (Eq, Show)

eval :: Expr -> Value
eval (IntE x) = IntV x
eval FalseE = BoolV False
eval TrueE = BoolV True
eval (AddE e1 e2)
  = let IntV v1 = eval e1  -- pattern match ensures right type
        IntV v2 = eval e2
    in  IntV (v1 + v2)
eval (SubE e1 e2)
  = let IntV v1 = eval e1
        IntV v2 = eval e2
    in  IntV (v1 - v2)
eval (EqE e1 e2) = BoolV (eval e1 == eval e2)  -- equal if same type and value
eval (OrE e1 e2)
  = let BoolV v1 = eval e1
        BoolV v2 = eval e2
    in  BoolV (v1 || v2)
eval (AndE e1 e2)
  = let BoolV v1 = eval e1
        BoolV v2 = eval e2
    in  BoolV (v1 && v2)

-- * Combined parser/interpreter with no intermediate AST

expr' :: Parser Value
expr' = chainl1 term' op
  where op = add <$ char '+'
         <|> sub <$ char '-'
         <|> eq  <$ char '='
         <|> or  <$ char '|'
         <|> and <$ char '&'
        add (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x + y
        sub (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x - y
        eq  v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        or  (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x || y
        and (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x && y
term' :: Parser Value
term' = IntV . read <$> some digit
   <|> BoolV False <$ char 'F' <|> BoolV True <$ char 'T'
   <|> parens expr'

-- * Parser/interpreter with operator precendence

expr0 :: Parser Value
expr0 = chainl1 expr1 op
  where op = or  <$ char '|'
        or  (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x || y
expr1 :: Parser Value
expr1 = chainl1 expr2 op
  where op = and <$ char '&'
        and (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x && y
expr2 :: Parser Value
expr2 = chainl1 expr3 op
  where op = eq  <$ char '='
        eq  v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
expr3 :: Parser Value
expr3 = chainl1 term'' op
  where op = add <$ char '+'  -- two operators at same precedence
         <|> sub <$ char '-'
        add (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x + y
        sub (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x - y
term'' :: Parser Value
term'' = IntV . read <$> some digit
     <|> BoolV False <$ char 'F' <|> BoolV True <$ char 'T'
     <|> parens expr0

-- * Alternate implementation using buildExpressionParser

expr0' :: Parser Value
expr0' = buildExpressionParser table term''
  where table = [ [binary '+' add, binary '-' sub]
                , [binary '=' eq]
                , [binary '&' and]
                , [binary '|' or]
                ]
        binary c op = Infix (op <$ char c) AssocLeft
        add (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x + y
        sub (IntV x) (IntV y) = IntV $ x - y
        eq  v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        and (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x && y
        or  (BoolV x) (BoolV y) = BoolV $ x || y

-- * Typed parser/interpreter with separate boolean and integer expressions

bexpr0 :: Parser Bool
bexpr0 = chainl1 bexpr1 op
  where op = (||) <$ char '|'
bexpr1 :: Parser Bool
bexpr1 = chainl1 bexpr2 op
  where op = (&&) <$ char '&'
bexpr2 :: Parser Bool
bexpr2 = False <$ char 'F' <|> True <$ char 'T'
     <|> try eqexpr
     <|> parens bexpr0
     where eqexpr = (==) <$> iexpr3 <* char '=' <*> iexpr3  -- this can't chain now
iexpr3 :: Parser Int
iexpr3 = chainl1 iterm op
  where op = (+) <$ char '+'
         <|> (-) <$ char '-'
iterm :: Parser Int
iterm = read <$> some digit
     <|> parens iexpr3

-- * Alternate definition of eqexpr to allow 4=2+2=1+3

eqexpr' = do
  x:xs <- sepBy1 iexpr3 (char '=')
  return $ all (==x) xs
```